# handle 2k image request a second with nginx

Tags: nginx, php, high-load

We have made an app that displays dynamic images. We are trying to handle a load of 2k image request a second with nginx. The size of the image is about 0.13 mb and we are using php with this code to serve the image:

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$file.'"');

echo file_get_contents($file);
```

When we load the server with 7500 request in 30 sec (250 a sec) we get this response: 
[screenshot of response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6OdT.png)

Here the average response is 5461 ms. 
We got  4GB Ram
40GB SSD Disk 
2 Core vp on digitalocean.com
Any suggestions on what we can do?

Comment: Don't have PHP send the file. That is slow. Instead have nginx send the file. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/

Comment: Thank you for the response, it helped alot! 
Do you have any more suggestions on what i could do, that would be much appreciated.